# netcat with ssh

Tags: ssh, nc

every time that I'll send a thing from computer **A** to computer **B** with **nc**, I to use these commands,

Computer **A**

```
tar cfp - film.mp4 | nc -w 3 192.168.xxx.xx 1234
```

Computer **B**

```
nc -l -p 1234 | tar xvfp -
```

My question, I have **openssh**, how can send mine videos, file, directories,.. with **ssh** and **nc**, without to used other programmes like **rsync**, **tar**, **sftp**,...

Very thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: Just use `scp` directly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, what as here **OpenSSH 8.0** says https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0 , **The scp protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. We
recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for
file transfer instead.**

Comment: It will still work for most purposes. If you don't want to use it, then use sftp, which is part of OpenSSH. I really don't see any use for `nc` here when SSH is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@muru's comment is very valid, but for the sake of academical purpose:

Computer **A**:

```
cat source | ssh user@ComputerB 'cat > destination'
```

(Assumes password-less authentication by public key.)

Comment: I have on both computer to write `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: sorryyyy, I write on `here@192.168.xxx.xx` my **hostname**, when i should to write my **username**.... Veryyy thanks! , I wish your a nice Day!